# How to update WSDL_Imp.exe in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have downloaded the updated version of WSDL_Imp.exe from http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24535. I followed the intructions to update the existing WSDLImporter.exe. However, I see no effect. Strangely, if I remove WSDL_Imp.exe from the bin folder, the WSDL importer from the D7 still runs. Could someone tell how to update it correctly so that the updated version runs when I used the WSDLImporter wizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an update to the command line importer and not the one embedded in the IDE.